# in r how to sort the lowest numeric value in multiple numeric columns and by group?

Tags: r, sorting, aggregate

** There are NAs in the min.range column**

In R, I have a dataframe with a list of species, each has two related columns with numeric values (overall.percentage and min.range). For each species, there are multiple lines (representing different populations).
This is a sample of the dataframe:

```
species<- data.frame(species= c("dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "fish", "fish"),
                 overall.percentage = c(12, 13, 19,  20, 12,  10, 50),
                 min.range= c(19, 19, 99,  1, 2,  NA, 26))
```

I would like to create a new column that orders all species (not population) according to the lowest value each species has in either of the 2 numeric columns.

The result of the above data will be:

```
species<- data.frame(species= c("dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "fish", "fish"),
                 overall.percentage = c(12, 13, 19,  20, 12,  10, 50),
                 min.range= c(19, 19, 99,  1, 2,  NA, 26),
 order = (3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2))
```

(explanation: '"cat" has "1" in "order" as it had the lowest value (i.e. "1") in either overall.percentage and min.range **out of all other species**. Fish had "2" as it has the second lowest value of "10", and "dog" has "3" as it has the less low value of 12).

I guess I need to:
(1) group the dataframe by species (with aggregate function?)
(2) select the lowest value within a species (while considering both numeric columns)
(3) and then create a new numeric column with a number for each species according to its order within all the species.
The end goal will be to use this new "order" column to order the species in ascending order for ggplotling.

I managed to use the aggregate function to find the minimum value within each species according to only one of the parameters, but not according to both:
min_by_species <- aggregate ((overall.percentage) ~ species.English.name, data = species, min)

Also, it is not clear to me how to create the "order" column later that will be used for the ggploting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option to achieve your desired result using `ave()`:

```r
species <- data.frame(
  species = c("dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "fish", "fish"),
  overall.percentage = c(12, 13, 19, 20, 12, 10, 50),
  min.range = c(19, 19, 99, 1, 2, 44, 26)
)

species |>
  transform(
    value = ave(
      pmin(overall.percentage, min.range), species,
      FUN = min
    )
  ) |>
  transform(
    order = as.numeric(
      reorder(species, value)
    )
  ) |> 
  subset(select = -value)
#>   species overall.percentage min.range order
#> 1     dog                 12        19     3
#> 2     dog                 13        19     3
#> 3     dog                 19        99     3
#> 4     cat                 20         1     1
#> 5     cat                 12         2     1
#> 6    fish                 10        44     2
#> 7    fish                 50        26     2
```

Comment: Thanks @stefan! Almost perfect. 2 comments though.
1) I had some NA in the numeric values, in this case, one has to change the code to: `species |>
  transform(
    value = ave(
      pmin(overall.percentage, min.range, na.rm = TRUE), species,
      FUN = min
    )
  ) |>
  transform(
    order = as.numeric(
      reorder(species, value)
    )
  ) |> 
  subset(select = -value)
`
2) When there are two species, each with multiple values, but both of them have the same minimum value, I would like the species whose second value is lower to have a lower rank order. How?

Answer (score 1):

A pipy solution assessing `min` and `order` after `unlist`ing in a `by` function followed by `unsplit` and `cbind`.

```
by(species[-1], species$species, unlist) |> sapply(min) |>
  order() |> unsplit(species$species) |> data.frame() |> setNames('order') |> 
  cbind(species)
#   order species overall.percentage min.range
# 1     3     dog                 12        19
# 2     3     dog                 13        19
# 3     3     dog                 19        99
# 4     1     cat                 20         1
# 5     1     cat                 12         2
# 6     2    fish                 10        44
# 7     2    fish                 50        26
```

Answer (score 0):

using @stefan solution

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(species= c("dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "fish", "fish"),
                    overall.percentage = c(12, 13, 19,  20, 12,  10, 50),
                    min.range= c(19, 19, 99,  1, 2,  44, 26))

df %>% 
  mutate(order = min(pmin(overall.percentage, min.range)), .by = species) %>% 
  mutate(order = dense_rank(order))
#>   species overall.percentage min.range order
#> 1     dog                 12        19     3
#> 2     dog                 13        19     3
#> 3     dog                 19        99     3
#> 4     cat                 20         1     1
#> 5     cat                 12         2     1
#> 6    fish                 10        44     2
#> 7    fish                 50        26     2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>