# In R, how to prioritize second minimum value when sorting multiple numeric columns by group?

Tags: r, sorting, aggregate

I recently used the code from the following question  [in r how to sort the lowest numeric value in multiple numeric columns and by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77294157/in-r-how-to-sort-the-lowest-numeric-value-in-multiple-numeric-columns-and-by-gro?newreg=67cdae306704447885c77cd2fbaf1592) to order my data in R from minimum to maximum values within group. Using @stefan's answer:

```
species <- data.frame(
  species = c("dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "fish"),
  overall.percentage = c(12, 13, 20, 12, 20)
)


species <- species |>
  transform(
    value = ave(
      pmin(overall.percentage), species,
      FUN = min
    )
  ) |>
  transform(
    order = as.numeric(
      reorder(species, value)
    )
  ) |> 
  subset(select = -value)
```

While the code efficiently handles scenarios where there are no ties in the minimum values among different groups, I've encountered a problem where multiple species share the same minimum value. Currently, the implementation prioritizes the order based on the first minimum value alone, without considering additional criteria.

In such cases, I want to ensure that the species with the lower second value is assigned a lower rank order.I'm seeking advice on how to modify the code to consider the second minimum value as a tiebreaker in ordering the species.

Comment: Hello @Dave2e, I've made some modifications to the sample code to enhance clarity. Currently, the order appears as follows: [2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3]. I would like the species to be sorted in the following order: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]. This means that the order of cats and dogs will be swapped. From what I understand the logic of `ave` is to computes the minimum value of the vector obtained from the pmin operation for each group.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a dataframe to ranking functions such as `row_number()` to use a second column to break ties:

```r
library(tidyverse)

species <- tibble(
  species = c("dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "fish", "fish", "lion"),
  overall.percentage = c(12, 13, 20, 12, 20, 50, 12)
)

find_min <- function(x, rank) {
  if (rank > length(x)) return(-Inf)
  x[row_number(x) == rank]
}

rank <- species |> 
  summarise(
    min_1 = find_min(overall.percentage, 1L),
    min_2 = find_min(overall.percentage, 2L),
    .by = species
  ) |> 
  mutate(rank = row_number(pick(min_1, min_2))) |> 
  select(species, rank)

species |> 
  left_join(rank, join_by(species))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>   species overall.percentage  rank
#>   <chr>                <dbl> <int>
#> 1 dog                     12     2
#> 2 dog                     13     2
#> 3 cat                     20     3
#> 4 cat                     12     3
#> 5 fish                    20     4
#> 6 fish                    50     4
#> 7 lion                    12     1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hey dufei, it looks like the code above is causing a runtime error.

Comment: For me it doesn't... Try restarting your R session perhaps?

Comment: Restart did work, thanks! However, the outcome is not quite what I'm aiming for. I would like to create a new column for ranking/order without changing the data frame/tibble, where each dog row are assigned the rank of 1, cats 2, and fish 3.

Comment: Well just merge it back, see updated code.

Comment: Thanks dufei! The only issue is that it fails when there is only one data point for a species(see updated sample). Any idea how adjust the code?

Comment: Then what would be your decision rule to break a tie in the first minimum if one group doesn't have a second minimum?

Comment: That the group with a single minimum will be assigned the lower rank.

Comment: Have a look at the updated code, hope that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `order` in `by`.

```
> by(species, species$species, \(x) x[order(x$overall.percentage), ]) |> unsplit(species$species)
  species overall.percentage sth
1     dog                 12   1
2     dog                 13   2
4     cat                 12   4
3     cat                 20   3
5    fish                 20   5
6    fish                 50   6
```

Added another column to the data beforehand to better demonstrate the result.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(species)
structure(list(species = c("dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "fish", 
"fish"), overall.percentage = c(12, 13, 20, 12, 20, 50), sth = 1:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```